# Numba @jit fails to speed up the performance of this function. Anyway to fix that?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, optimization, numba

I am quite new to the numba package in python. I am not sure if I am using the numba.jit correctly, but the code just runs too slow with 23.7s per loops over the line: Z1 = mmd(X,Y,20)
What is the correct way to optimize the code? I need your help guys. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.jit
def mmd(array1, array2, n):
    n1 = array1.shape[0]
    MMD = np.empty(n1, dtype = 'float64')

    for i in range(n-1,n1):
        MMD[i] = np.average(abs(array1[i+1-n:i+1] - array2[i]))

    return MMD

X = np.array([i**2 for i in range(1000000)])
Y = np.array([i for i in range(1000000)])
Z1 = mmd(X,Y,20)
```

EDIT: simplified the code even further

EDIT2: tried @nb.jit(nopython = True), then there is an error message:

```
KeyError: "<class 'numba.targets.cpu.CPUTargetOptions'> does not support option: 'nonpython'"
```

also tried:

```
@nb.jit(nb.float32[:](nb.float32[:],nb.float32[:],nb.int8))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make Numba work well you need to use "nopython" mode, as you mentioned.  To enable this, simply run the program with `jit` replaced by `njit` (or equivalently, `jit(nopython=True)`, and fix the errors one by one:

1. np.empty() doesn't support the `dtype='float64'` argument in Numba.  That's OK though, because float64 is the default.  Just remove it.
2. np.average() is not supported in Numba.  That's OK, since we are not passing any weights anyway, it's the same as np.mean().  Replace it.
3. The built-in abs() is not supported in Numba.  Use np.abs() instead.

We end up with this:

```
@nb.njit
def mmd(array1, array2, n):
    n1 = array1.shape[0]
    MMD = np.empty(n1)

    for i in range(n-1,n1):
        MMD[i] = np.mean(np.abs(array1[i+1-n:i+1] - array2[i]))

    return MMD
```

And it is 100x faster.

Bonus tips:

1. You can initialize your sample data more concisely and faster like this:

   ```
   Y = np.arange(1000000)
   X = Y * Y
   ```
2. The first n values in the result are uninitialized garbage.  You might want to clean that up somehow.

Comment: Can't thank you enough John. I wonder, though, where is the best place to learn stuff like njit in details?